# GAE search API - how to geoSearch a field

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hello I am having a difficult time geoSearching a field.  What I am trying to do is query the geofield to find the closest store to me based on the zipcode I provide.

First i get the lat & lng from google maps api (components:postal_code:). Then I input the lat & lng coordinates into the query string.

EX.  query = "distance(store_location, geopoint(lat, lng)) < 4500"

My index is populated with plenty of documents...store_location is my geoField

EX. store_location | search.GeoPoint(latitude=34.0324...)

The PROBLEM is... when ever I search the index i get back zero

EX. search.SearchResults(number_found=0)

Why am I not getting back a result? Thank you for the help.

```
class FindStore(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = zipcheck.get_lat_lng_from_google_map(self.request.body)
        obj = json.loads(data)
        ziplat = obj['lat']
        ziplng = obj['lng']
        index = INDEX_STORE
        query = "distance(store_location, geopoint(%s, %s)) < 4500" %(ziplat, ziplng)
        results = index.search(query)
        return results
```

Comment: Ric, you figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Do you have the issue also on Production environment? Do you see your indexes in the Admin console, Full Text Search section (localhost:8000 by default)?